# Infinitely many distinct minimal tori

Tags: riemannian-geometry, 3-manifolds, minimal-surfaces, torus

Let $M = \Sigma_g \times \mathbb{S}^1$ be endowed with the product metric, where $\Sigma_g$ is a compact orientable surface of genus $g$ with an arbitrary fixed metric. Is it true that there are infinitely many noncongruent embedded minimal tori in $M$?

Comment: any closed geodesic $\gamma$ in $\Sigma_g$ yields a minimal torus by crossing with $S^1$

Comment: Even when $\Sigma_g$ is a sphere?

Comment: Oh I assumed you were excluding that case. If $g=0$, then what I said shows that there are at least 3 such tori (since there are at least 3 simple closed geodesics). But it is not clear if there are infinitely many tori. It seems like it is more or less equivalent to the question of whether or not there are tori which are not S^1 invariant. (Also, it isnt clear if you are referring to a canonical metric on $\Sigma$ or abitrary?)

Comment: The metric on $\Sigma$ is arbitrary.